# I'm trying to pick a framework for a product I'm about to build, and so far I'm leaning toward Nagare... Any thoughts?

Tags: java, javascript, python, frameworks

http://www.nagare.org/

As far as the type of product and framework usage, think something like Facebook (it's not exactly a social network, but close enough for evaluation in this context).

Basically, I'm just looking for something robust, scalable, easy to work with (small learning curve is a plus), compatible with older browsers, and well integrated with other technologies (e.g. Postgres, unless there's a compelling case to be made for Cassandra?).

Other frameworks/tools I've looked a bit at or been recommended:

- Google Web Toolkit + Server-side Java
- Django
- Ruby on Rails
- ASP.NET + Mono? (I know...)
- PHP/Perl/BBQ

I don't have a whole lot of experience with Web frameworks, so no matter what we end up choosing (whether I've mentioned it or not) I'll be learning something new. Any thoughts or recommendations? Anyone have any experience with Nagare (or Pyjamas)?

Comment: If you're new to web frameworks then I would suggest to go for Django - because you need support at various stages and Nagare doesn't have that much community compared to Django...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest **[Django](http://djangoproject.com)** + **[Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com)**. Both are robust and have less learning curve (if you have familiarity with Python).

This should have you a social network up & running within a day or two.

For the front-end use the usual suspects. javascript, css, html. I believe there are some terrific libraries for javascript.

Comment: @user459881 in keeping with good practices at StackOverflow, please upvote any answer that has helped you and finally mark the 'one' answer that has helped you the most as 'correct' (green check).

Comment: the dev community is really strong in Django (hence in pinax). So if you get stuck somewhere, help is in close call. I am not sure how active is Nagare. Django too is really quick & if you design your DB well, it's really quick. Look at some of the top websites which run on Django. This should take care of the basic backend i.e. server side.

Comment: reg. frontend, for javascript use jQuery or mootools or scriptaculos. All of these are excellent libraries. For html+css you have a pretty good template engine in Django itself. You culd use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Do you have any thoughts on this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990319/django-gwt-or-jquery The first reply references a method of connecting Pyjamas with Django, which would be nice as far as having an all-Python codebase and a quick frontend (the GWT approach seems to be faster than jQuery from what I've read).

Comment: in terms of features there is hardly any difference. It comes down to what you are comfortable with or what you want to try out. You could choose either or pyjs. No correct answer here.

Comment: Okay, awesome, thanks. I'll just go with Pyjamas then until I run into an unresolvable issue.

Answer (score 4):

As the lead developer of Nagare, I really encourage you to try it in real on your product, which is the best way to see how Nagare is truely different than the others frameworks like Django, Pylons or Flask. Nagare is components oriented (it shares the same components model than [Seaside](http://www.seaside.st/)) and its set of advance features like direct callbacks registration, stateful components, Ajax without to write any Javascript code or the use of continuations makes a Web application looks like a desktop one. In fact we have often found that developers like you, without prior Web experiences, can be quicker to get Nagare because they have nothing to "unlearn".

Talking about reliability, scabability and compatibility, you can check some of our [important projects](http://www.nagare.org/trac/wiki/PagesJaunesEureka) in production today.

For more info, don't hesitate to ask and share your experiences with [us](http://www.nagare.org/trac/wiki/NagareCommunity).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the response; I never expected to hear back from the lead developer of Nagare on this :P. I've actually decided to run a Django backend (the Pinax framework was just too compelling to pass up due to the nature of my project), but I am very much interested in using Nagare or Pyjamas for my frontend (Nagare seems to be based on Pyjamas, if I'm not mistaken?). Beyond what's available in Pyjamas and Django, does Nagare offer significant functionality? If so, how well does Nagare integrate with Django and how does its performance compare to pure Pyjamas? Thanks.

Comment: The link provided by apoirier has become invalid since he wrote this answer. I think the best corresponding page is : http://www.nagare.org/trac/wiki/WhoUsesNagare