# I need a good web development framework for Python

Tags: python

I'm a C/C++ developer and I also have experience developing web apps with C#, ASP.NET MVC and fluent nhibernate. I'm looking for non-MS alternatives for web development and I'm really interested in python so I went out after Django but I've been told that Django makes it difficult for me to personalize my HTML (not sure if this is accurate).

What I'm looking for is a Python web development framework that is integrated with an ORM, is able to generate the interfaces BUT provides an easy way for me to customize the interface to create an AJAX intensive app

Comment: I customize my HTML in Django all the time. I'm doing it right now in another window.

Comment: django customization is just as easy as any other high-powered web application frameworks.

Comment: Agreed django is customizable.  Django doesn't have ajax stuff built in; but there are plugins to do it, and its not difficult to put it in yourself.

Comment: What does "personalize your HTML" even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various options in Python you can look at -

1. Django (obviously!)
2. Pylons
3. Nagare
4. Flask

Django is really good. And no your info is not correct, HTML templates are real easy to edit them.

Also this is [from a developer of Nagare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921312/im-trying-to-pick-a-framework-for-a-product-im-about-to-build-and-so-far-im-l/3921380#3921380) -

> Ajax without to write any Javascript
>   code or the use of continuations makes
>   a Web application looks like a desktop
>   one. In fact we have often found that
>   developers like you, without prior Web
>   experiences, can be quicker to get
>   Nagare because they have nothing to
>   "unlearn".

I am going deeper into this framework Since you said that your app is AJAX intensive. From what I have heard, Nagare makes it easy to do so...

All these frameworks are really good. Some are really good in some areas, others not. So may be explore them all & see which best suits your purpose.

Answer (score 7):

go for [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).

- does all you wanted,
- has perfect docs and even [free book](http://www.djangobook.com/),
- partially runs on appengine,
- has really large user base,
- it is mature:

  - db sharding, (With model router)
  - xss protection in forms
  - memcache,
  - localisation,
  - well tested support for unicode,
  - really easy to learn because of level of it documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Flask (a very minimal web framework) and SQLAlchemy as my ORM.  I'm exceedingly happy with it.  Disclaimer: I'm only using this for personal projects at the moment, though I do plan to launch a web app in the next 6 months using this setup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in agreement with the rest of the answers and think that Django is by-far the best choice as a "complete framework" and I think their template system is second-to-none.

If you are looking to create an ajax intensive application, I'd suggestion checking out django-piston (http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home).  Piston is a REST API framework built on top of Django.  I've used it for a number of ajax intensive applications and have found it's workflow to be incredibly clean, quick and flexible.

If you are wanting to go a bit slimmer and lighter-weight though, I'd suggest checking out web.py (http://webpy.org/) or Tornado (http://www.tornadoweb.org/).

Answer (score 1):

For Web applications development, we're using [Nagare](http://www.nagare.org), coming with YUI for AJAX communications.
Having a look to Nagare might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look into [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) which is very thoroughly documented and has sql alchemy (one of the best python ORM's) baked in. Plus it's easy to setup and learn.

I currently am working with a framework called [restish](http://ish.io/projects/show/restish) which is flavor of pylons that (surprise, surprise) puts the focus on sticking to RESTful web design. I don't think it's exactly what you're looking for in that it lacks good documentation and any form of an ORM.

Just A side note I'm pretty sure that Django uses [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) templating which gives you excellent control over the HTML.

Comment: Django doesn't use Mako, it uses its own templating engine.