# Django to save the form details in database and retrieve back using ajax

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-ajax-selects

I want to save details in database and retrieve back to same page using Ajax. I added the code for your reference. Kindly share your ideas.

*models.py*

```
class Personal(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    name=models.CharField()
    dob = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    address1 = models.CharField()
    address2 = models.CharField()
    country = models.CharField()
    state = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
```

*Views.py*

```
def profile(request):
    userid=request.user.id
    personal=JSPersonal.objects.filter(user_id=userid)
    return render(request,'registration/profile.html', {'personal':personal})
```

*templates(profile.html)*

```
{% if personal %}
{% for p in personal %}
<p>Name : {{p.name}}</p>
<p>DOB : {{p.dob}}</p>
<p>Email : {{p.email}}</p>
<p>Address1 : {{p.address1}}</p>
<p>Address2 : {{p.address2}}</p>
<p>Country : {{p.country}}</p>
<p>State : {{p.state}}</p>
<p>City:{{p.city}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{%else%}
<p>Click <a href="#">Here</a> to add details</p>
{% endif %}
```

By clicking the "Here" model form get loaded here there is a space to enter the personal details.Here I need to store details in database and return back to same page once I click submit button in the model form. Only particular content get loaded not whole page.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you put an element with an ID around the data that will change, and target that id with a `jQuery.load` call.

see: [Render a django table using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518206/render-a-django-table-using-ajax/17518607#17518607)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the forms for such tasks: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

In this case, you can easily send your form with jQuery $.post():

```
$.post('/form/url/', $('form_selector').serialize())
  .done(function(data) { ... })
  .fail(function(jqXHR) { ... });
```

A more detailed response:
[How to POST a django form with AJAX & jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335780/how-to-post-a-django-form-with-ajax-jquery)