# How to change url path while switching pages via AJAX and Django?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am following this answer to make smooth page switches:
[Rendering JSON objects using a Django template after an Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882215/rendering-json-objects-using-a-django-template-after-an-ajax-call)

How do I make Django understand, that I'm on the other page already?

I want the list element to obtain 'active' class and to have /leaders/ in browser url path when I click on the link and load leaderboard template.
Say i have:

leaderboard.html:

```
<li{% if path == leaders %} class="active"{% endif %}>  
   <a href="/leaders/">Leaderboard</a>
</li>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^leaders/$', 'index.views.leaderboard', name='leaders'),
```

view:

```
def leaderboard(request):
  ...
  if request.is_ajax():
    return_str = render_block_to_string('leaderboard.html', 'block_name', context)
    return HttpResponse(return_str)
  else:
    response = render_to_response('leaderboard.html', context)
    return response
```

**Edit:** I've tried to use window.history.pushState, it changed url in browser, but did not tell anything to django.

Comment: See [broweserstate/history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) on GitHub.

Comment: You don't have to tell Django. You have to tell your html/css, which Django has absolutely nothing to do with after it has initially rendered the template.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1468/3033586

Comment: @SeledkaLebedka When you change the URL, you'll need to issue an AJAX request to *tell Django* in order to get new data.